# Optimization of simple SQL query with window function

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table constructed as

```
  a  |  b  |  c
-----+-----+-----
   3 |   2 |   1
   1 |   5 |   1
   8 |   4 |   1
   2 |   5 |   1
   4 |   4 |   2
   2 |   5 |   2
   9 |   3 |   2
   3 |   5 |   3
   2 |   5 |   3
   4 |   4 |   3
   5 |   6 |   3
   9 |   7 |   3
```

I want to compute the average value of `a` for each value of `c` where `b` is below a given value — e.g. the average of `b`.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT avg(a) FROM mytable t WHERE b<(SELECT avg(b) FROM mytable WHERE c=t.c) GROUP BY c;
```

I actually have two issues, but I believe they both belong to this single question (the first one will actually allow me to update the title) :

1. Is there a particular name or expression for this kind of query (I mean, operations on subselections and reintegration in the main query, or something like that) ?  I couldn't find how to even search for a solution online… => ok, window functions.
2. This query is very slow, how can I optimize it ?  I'm using 9.3.5, and `b`'s are already sorted in numerical order.

Thanks.

**Update :** Edit on user17130's answer [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5795387), but this answer won't work from scratch, so here is the working piece of code :

```
explain select 
   avg(a) 
   from  
   (
       select  
        avg(b) over (partition by c) as b_avg,
        a,
        b,
        c 
        from mytable
    ) as t 
    where b<b_avg 
    group by c;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=135.34..202.46 rows=67 width=8)
   Subquery Scan on t  (cost=135.34..198.39 rows=647 width=8)
     Filter: ((t.b)::numeric < t.b_avg)
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=135.34..169.29 rows=1940 width=12)
           ->  Sort  (cost=135.34..140.19 rows=1940 width=12)
                 Sort Key: mytable.c
                 ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=12)
```

Comment: Look into window functions and the HAVING clause.

Comment: It's much easier to search for the right terms indeed, thanks !  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Post the explain analyze (using explain.depesz.com preferebly). "very slow" is a bit too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you mean to do. This only has one table scan  using window functions. As you can see your query below is estimated to cost a lot more running time than this one. Without any selective conditions your going to have scan the table at least once.

```
 explain select                                                                     
    a_avg
    from
    (
        select
         avg(a) over (partition by c) as a_avg  
        ,avg(b) over (partition by c) as b_avg
        ,c
        ,b
        from mytable
    ) as t
    where b < b_avg
;
                                  QUERY PLAN                                  
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 Subquery Scan on t  (cost=135.34..203.24 rows=647 width=32)
   Filter: ((t.b)::numeric < t.b_avg)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=135.34..174.14 rows=1940 width=12)
         ->  Sort  (cost=135.34..140.19 rows=1940 width=12)
               Sort Key: mytable.c
               ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=12)
 Planning time: 0.128 ms
(7 rows)
```

...

```
crow@test=# explain SELECT avg(a) FROM mytable t WHERE b<(SELECT avg(b) FROM mytable WHERE c=t.c) GROUP BY c;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 HashAggregate  (cost=66560.08..66560.92 rows=67 width=8)
   Group Key: t.c
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable t  (cost=0.00..66556.85 rows=647 width=8)
         Filter: ((b)::numeric < (SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=34.28..34.29 rows=1 width=4)
                 ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..34.25 rows=10 width=4)
                       Filter: (c = t.c)
 Planning time: 0.191 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Your code didn't do exactly what I expected from scratch, but your answer helped dramatically, so I edited it with the corrected code.

Comment: Edit was rejected, see updated question for the working code.